# Python Multithreading Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-multithreading

I am writing a code in Tkinter with a button that starts 6 selenium chrome instances, each with a different url. The goal is : the drivers have to be initiated in the fastest possible way and every driver instance has to reenter its specific url (refresh) every 4 seconds. Every driver is attached to a class, that contains the wanted url. I tried this with threads:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browsers = []

class Browser:
    def __init__(self, url, session_file):
        self.url = url
        self.session_file = session_file


def manipulate_browser(browser):

    browser.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    while True:
        browser.driver.get(browser.url)
        time.sleep(4)



def start_browsers():

    for browser in browsers:
        browser.thread = threading.Thread(target=manipulate_browser, args=(browser,))
        browser.thread.start()


if __name__=='__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = []
    urls = 'https://google.com', 'https://facebook.com', 'https://instagram.com', 'https://snapchat.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com', 'https://amazon.com', 'https://microsoft.com'#, 'https://stackoverflow.com', 'https://youtube.com', 'https://yahoo.com'
    for url in urls:
        session_file = 'session_' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
        newBrowser = Browser(url, session_file)
        browsers.append(newBrowser)


    root = tk.Tk()                    
    button_start_browsers = tk.Button(root, command=start_browsers, width=50, height=4, bg='red', text='Start Browsers')
    button_start_browsers.pack()
```

And this works just fine, but I want to add some options and capabilities to the driver, in the `manipulate_browser` function . Like so:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import os
import time
import random, string

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

browsers = []

class Browser:
    def __init__(self, url, session_file):
        self.url = url
        self.session_file = session_file


def manipulate_browser(browser):
    global lock
    with lock:
        caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
        caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.mkdir(current_dir + '\\' + browser.session_file) 
        chrome_options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=' + current_dir + '\\' + browser.session_file + '\\selenium')

        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=750,750")

    browser.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=caps)

    while True:
        browser.driver.get(browser.url)
        time.sleep(4)



def start_browsers():

    for browser in browsers:
        browser.thread = threading.Thread(target=manipulate_browser, args=(browser,))
        browser.thread.start()


if __name__=='__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()
    threads = []
    urls = 'https://google.com', 'https://facebook.com', 'https://instagram.com', 'https://snapchat.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com', 'https://amazon.com', 'https://microsoft.com'#, 'https://stackoverflow.com', 'https://youtube.com', 'https://yahoo.com'
    for url in urls:
        session_file = 'session_' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
        newBrowser = Browser(url, session_file)
        browsers.append(newBrowser)


    root = tk.Tk()                    
    button_start_browsers = tk.Button(root, command=start_browsers, width=50, height=4, bg='red', text='Start Browsers')
    button_start_browsers.pack()
```

After implementing this, it doesn't work anymore : meaning : sometimes, I get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` And all the threads seem to work on just one driver (the last one). I believe this is because the threads mix with each other so I have to use a lock, but putting this line `browser.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=caps)` under the lock will affect drastically my speed, that I need. I also understand that I have to use `ThreadPool`, for avoiding thread mixing and I tried it, but it freezed the GUI app. Another option that others suggest is implementing queue with threads, which I am not very familiar with. I also thought of trying multiprocessing, but the maximum numbers of processes depends on every machine characteristics, from my understanding, and maybe I want to start more processes than that.  How can I workaround this situation to achieve my goal? What is the best way?

(Note : I've done plenty of research regarding my issue, but I still couldn't figure it out. Any help is welcomed !)

**EDIT :**
Due to multiple testing, I figured out that the line `chrome_options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=' + current_dir + '\\' + browser.session_file + '\\selenium')` may cause all the problems. This line keeps the chrome sessions all in one icon and I really like this feature and I wouldn't like getting rid of it. How can I overcome the issue, knowing this information? Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Does it work without `Tkinter`?

Comment: No, it still doesn't seem to work. In general, I get the same error : `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.`